# Android <receiver> - BroadcastReceiver not called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have specified a receiver in the manifest like so ..

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.me.MyProject"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:enabled="true">

    <service android:name="MyService" 
             android:exported="true"
             android:process=":different" 
             android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.me.MyService">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:exported="true" 
              android:name="MySMSBroadcastReceiver" 
              android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

If I test this on an Android Froyo device (emulator or real) this works as I expect. The MySMSBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(...) is being called when the device receives an SMS.

However if I install this on a 4.0 or 4.1 device (either emulator or a real device) nothing happens on an incoming message. No errors, no  nothing. I also changed the properties for the project to target a 4.0 or 4.1 device specifically and re-installed it but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After your application is installed, the user need to launch an activity of yours manually before any of your BroadcastReceivers will have an effect, **as of Android 3.1**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there no way around this? My application does not have an Activity and the service that is listed in the manifest is not running.

Comment: @Lieuwe  I am not sure but as i think there is no way to do this. its all about the android security and no one can break this.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the receiver on OS startup giving the right permissions.

Comment: That won't work either unless the user has launched the activity (which doesn't exist at the moment) at least once.